# Error loading [http://localhost:8888/testWS]: java.lang.Exception: Failed to load url; http://localhost:8888/testWS, 0

Tags: java, soap, jax-ws, soapui

I've been following this tutorial on how to create web services in Java. The code that I've followed are as follows:

```
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding;
import javax.xml.ws.Endpoint;

@WebService
@SOAPBinding(style = SOAPBinding.Style.DOCUMENT)
public class TestService {

    @WebMethod
    public String sayHello(String msg){
        return "Hello "+msg;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Endpoint.publish("http://localhost:8888/testWS", new TestService());
    }
}
```

The said tutorial instructed that I should just run the main method and I should be able to invoke it in the SoapUI. But each time I try to invoke the URL, I always get an error as mentioned in title. Am I missing something?

Comment: In almost all environments the URL should be http://localhost:8888/testWS?wsdl try and run it again and see if that works.  If it does I can try and answer the question as to why it works.

Comment: I can't believe it was that simple. Thank you very much. That "?wsdl" was not mentioned in the tutorial. Thanks a lot again.

Comment: You're welcome Uzi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks OK, but it depends on how you're invoking the service. If you're using soapUI, create a new SOAP project and specify `http://localhost:8888/testWS?wsdl` as the initial WSDL:

[image]

Then, you can invoke the service by supplying a value in the request payload:

[image]

Comment: That "?wsdl" was not mentioned in the tutorial. Thanks for the help. So simple